Why do I keep receiving "Quota exceeded" error for partition modification while I am way below the quotas provided by BigQuery?
I use dbt to update some BigQuery tables that are column-partitioned. However some dbt runs started to fail with the following error:

Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition modifications to a column partitioned table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

My understanding is that table materialization that uses the CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE is not impacted by quotas, only incremental models are. However our most demanding incremental model runs twice per hour and updates 3 partitions which represents 144 updates partitions per day. The limit is 30 000 according to BigQuery documentation.
I also followed the troubleshooting steps listed here, including running the query below, but it just confirms that I am still very far from reaching the limits as the maximum number of modified partitions was 156 on a given day.
SELECT
  DATE(creation_time) AS date,
  destination_table.table_id,
  SUM(total_modified_partitions) AS total_modified_partitions
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
GROUP BY
  date,
  table_id
ORDER BY
  total_modified_partitions DESC

Did anyone encounter a similar problem? Do you know what could be the reason for getting this error?

Hi ,The limit is 30 000 according to BigQuery documentation. this is for Column-Partitioned Table .

Hi, yes the tables are column-partitioned. I updated the post. Thanks.

Hi @MBL, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
